# class not found.CORDOVA PHONEGAP

Tags: android, cordova

I can't run the test application posted on git "phonegap-nfc-reader-master" and all the other applications with this plugin.
I'm struggling with nfc plugin of cordova because of this error. I think It's a problem of file loading (the order). I have read all the other related answers but was useless.
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/32

I have a Samsun galaxy s2 mini and compile with phonegap version 3.4.0-0.19.17 and cordova 3.4.1-0.1.0.

Comment: Have you verified that you have actually added the plugin to your project before building and running the test app?

Comment: Yes. I have verified.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to plugin configuration. cordova based plugins can create issue with phonegap command. try using cordova command

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work with cordova it gives the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: check if plugin supports cordova 3.4 version.

Comment: Error adding ndef listener: "class not found"